# Still getting a Graph API v2 upgrade warning on Android for facebook login after upgrade

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've just upgraded my js api to v2.2, and my php sdk to v4, and my login with these new code bases is working fine.

However, if the user is logged out of Facebook when they attempt to log into my app, the Facebook login pop up is displaying the warning 'You must upgrade to v2.x...'

Does this warning display regardless if you've upgraded, or only for apps that haven't yet been upgraded?

Comment: I think you see that warning based on the percentage of your Graph API calls that are still using v1.x. Since end users can take a while to update your app, it's possible to see this even after you've already updated the code.

Comment: @Ming Li - how do we know if we've successfully upgraded then?

Comment: @Ming Li - where did you see the info about the warning being triggered by the percentage of Graph API calls still using v1.x? Cheers.

Comment: Oh, I think we're talking about different banners. Sorry for the confusion.